# Laravel - Failed to load resource

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the Image Intervention package in Laravel and I can't display my profile image. The problem is that the browser fails to load the resource

```
localhost:8000/uploads etc.
```

All files are saved in public folder :

```
public/uploads
```

My view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <img src="uploads/{{ $user->avatar }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return view ('user.profile', array('user'=>Auth::user()));
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatar' . $filename));
            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }
        return view('user.profile',array('user'=>Auth::user()));
    }
}
```

I'm using windows and i see these files saved in my folder public/uploads but i cant display it

Regards

Comment: You are saving to `/uploads/avatar'.$filename`, but when you look for the file it seems you are looking for `/uploads/$filename`. Could you check this?

Comment: What is the error exactly? Is there a line that XDebug gives you?

Comment: when i save to/uploads/avatar'.$filename it saves me in uploads folder with name avatar$filename

Comment: and the error is that the path to img is wrong and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: you can access to your views with `localhost:8000/someview`?

Comment: yes. My profile view is localhost:8000/profile but it doesn't show image because of failed to load resource

Comment: Ok i saw that my files are saved avatar12345.jpg for example and it loads only 12345.jpg how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller class change this line:

```
$user->avatar = $filename;
```

to this:

```
$user->avatar = 'avatar' . $filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you save the image, add a `/` after "uploads/avatar":

`save(public_path('/uploads/avatar/' . $filename));`

That should solve the naming problem. Then in your HTML add "avatar/" after "uploads/", as you are saving to the "upload/avatar" folder.

Then your view would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
        <img src="uploads/avatar/{{ $user->avatar }}">
    </div>
</div>
```